# How to download videos from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, itunes-u

I wanted to download these [Stanford](http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/quantum-mechanics/2012/winter) and [MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/rss.xml) lectures. Unfortunately, they are all privatized by iMac. Do you see that all download links bring to itunes.com site? BTW, why are all the best world universities are subsumed by Apple? I have installed the iTunes, but I still do not see the Download button. All it does is play online.

Here is how the iTunes download page looks like [image]

You may enjoy the [DPI-aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) perfect Mac interface. But, where is the "Download" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay up with the entire course, press the large subscribe button and you will then get a warning that explains a bit more about how the process works.

[image: iTunes U dialog]

At that point, you can double check what content you want to actually download (just like a podcast works) and you will of course have to enter an AppleID with payment set up if the specific course you have chosen requires such for some or all of the materials.

You can also press the free buttons along the right to download individual lessons to your computer (or iOS device) for offline viewing.

Comment: Thanks, subscribe downloads the file. I have realized that because iTunes started to kill my Hard Drive. It as thrashed for 10 minutes. I have recorded the file access with Process Monitor and observed that it opens/closes 5 files for every 64k downloaded. Thereby, it calls Flush 2 times. I suppose the latter is the cause of the huge thrashing and, thus, kills the drive.

Comment: Observing iTunes download process through ProcMon is very useful because it also show user the download location of his mp4 file. This is very useful because stupid iTunes does not show anything up in its <strike>stupid</strike> perfect  iTunes interface neither when I "subscribed", nor when <strike>thrashing</strike> download has finished. Thank you Apple for the lesson of neat design. This is really a new way of thinking.

Comment: Well, I have discovered the video and its location in the `My Libraries > Recently added`. Thanks. But, Process Monitor is more useful anyway, since I wanted to play the video with double speed, using VLC player, and Process Monitor allows you to *copy the file locaion* and jump to it. I still did not realize the point of thrashing the playlist file.

Comment: Downloading = your disk is thrashed 10 min for every file. I do not want to use this method.